# Access postgres DB from two applications

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, database-connection, load-balancing

I am performing load balancing for my application. I have made two application servers, say A and B. That access the same database (Postgres) using Hibernate.

The problem arises when the system moves from A to B. Most of the things are working fine, but at some points (While reading data from db) the system automatically logs the user out.

Is this because of synchronization with db?

Is there some kind of lock on the database when one application is accessing the database?

What do i need to do in-order to get it working?

It'll be a great help.

Comment: Did you set the load balancer to have session affinity? (don't worry if you don't know what this mean)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "the system automatically logs the user out"? Do you mean the *Postgres* connection gets closed? Or your application-level login?

Comment: @gerrytan: I am not using any tool for load balancing, i am just switching the application servers as soon as one goes down. And, i did not set anything regarding the session affinity too, i don't know where to set it.

Comment: @khampson: I was referring to the application-level login, Can Postgres connection be closed automatically?. Because the application keeps running. Only it closes the user session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the *Postgres* server can terminate connections for various reasons (i.e. if an admin does so), generally that would be a client-side thing, which in your case is likely *Hiberate* as a *Spring DAO*. If your app-level login is being closed, it's likely to be an issue with how your app is logging back in on the other server.

Most likely, you have entirely separate *DAO* instances on each server, and so when the switch from app-server A to B occurs mid DB read, it has to start over from the beginning on the new server, including authentication, et al.

I'm assuming each is deployed in its own *WAR* and has the *DAO* injected at runtime, at which point the connection to *Postgres* is made. (You could add logging in your dependency-injection code to determine more.)

In addition to the separate database connections, it appears it doesn't handle failover to the other server without requiring re-logging in. That shouldn't be related directly to *Postgres*, at least not the connection. It would depend on how you're persisting the login. i.e. if it's cached locally, that would also have two separate instances in each app, and the authentication would need to reoccur. If the credentials are stored in *Postgres*, the connection would first need to be obtained before re-authenticating.

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

Since they are two separate app instances, a load balancer alone would not work, since that would most likely depend on the request being (mostly) stateless. If you authenticated via a token which was either in the URL or the header, a load balancer would work, since the the auth token would be redirected also, and while reauthentication would need to happen in the backend, authentication should be granted if the token is valid, and the app should essentially stay logged in. It doesn't sound like you're using auth tokens, though.

In short, which two separate instances, the authentication really always needs to happen on every request, but how that's managed can vary. You could look into an *OAuth* solution, for example, but that may be overkill for your needs.

In any case, you should avoid taking state straight from the client, since that can be tampered with. If the server were to failover cleanly (say, for load purposes), you could control that security handover in the app logic by propagating the security context to the other instance, although that could get a bit unwieldy.

However, during an *unclean* failover (say, if the JVM heap limit is reached), that wouldn't be possible -- you would need an external authentication system that the other app could query using the supplied credentials, determine the request is authenticated, and allow the request to proceed.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I have separate DAO instances on each server which are contained in their own WAR. And thus it is attempting re-authentication.

But the problem is how do i avoid it? Is there anything i can do at the code level? Or i have to configure my load-balancer setting?